# GCC compiling source and library

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction

I have my main C file, another C file (which I'm using as a library) and two header files containing the function prototypes for each C file.

How can I compile and link them into one executable file with GCC? I'd like to use the `-o` and `-g` flags too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gcc -g -c first_file.c
gcc -g -c second_file.c
gcc -o executable first_file.o second_file.o
```

In general though, try googling for a `gcc` tutorial first.